# ASP.NET - Get Security Groups for User

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website that is running on the Intranet with Integrated Windows Security.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authorization>
    <allow roles="MyDomain\Group1,MyDomain\Group2"/>
</authorization>
```

How do I determine if the current user belongs to MyDomain\Group1 or MyDomain\Group2.  I tried this below, but it throws an error back:

```
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, "MyDomain\Group1");
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> user = UserPrincipal.Current.GetGroups();

        foreach (Principal principal in group.Members)
        {
            if (UserPrincipal.Current.Name == principal.Name)
            {
                // Enable Functionality

                break;
            }
        }
```

How do I determine if the current user belongs to Mydomain\Group1 or Mydomain\Group2?

Comment: "but it throws an error back" you forgot to provide the error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Active Directory API, you can simply use the Roles class:

[Roles.GetRolesForUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ak75t41.aspx)

Just add this to your web.config:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="WindowsProvider" 
  enabled="true"
  cacheRolesInCookie="false">
  <providers>
    <add name="WindowsProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowstokenroleprovider.aspx for more information.